# Attaching iWork documents from iCloud Document Picker does not work because they are directories not files

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, icloud

Converting any iWork documents (`Pages`, `Keynote`, `Numbers`) into `NSData` from the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` does not seem to be working since they are not files but directories.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *fileName = [[url path] lastPathComponent];
NSData *fileData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:[docPickerUrl path]];
NSString *fileExtension = [docPickerUrl pathExtension];
NSString *UTI = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge CFStringRef)fileExtension, NULL);
NSString *contentType = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass((__bridge CFStringRef)UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
```

fileData is always `nil` since `NSFileManager` can't convert directory to data.

I get `url` from `- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue here: [iOS8: UIDocumentPickerViewController get NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520453/ios8-uidocumentpickerviewcontroller-get-nsdata)

The solution is to add iWork documents as zip archives, the simplest way is to use [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive) library, also available as cocoa pod:

```
pod 'SSZipArchive', '~> 0.3'
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend going through a NSFileCoordinator object, which is AFAIK required for accessing security-scoped files such as those through Dropbox and iCloud. (Uncomment the first and next-to-last lines in the code below in that case.) The `options` parameter you want for NSFIleCoordinator's `coordinateReadingItemAtURL:` is `NSFileCoordinatorReadingForUploading`. This will read in single files normally, but will turn directories into zip files automatically. Strip off the `.zip` that is added on and you'll have a valid Pages/Numbers/Keynote file. (It's valid with it on too.)

```
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url {
  //[url startAccessingSecurityScopedResource]; // Necessary for security-scoped files
  NSFileCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] init];
  NSError *error;
  __block NSData *fileData;

  [coordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:url options:NSFileCoordinatorReadingForUploading error:&error byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL) {
     // File name for use in writing the file out later
     NSString *fileName = [newURL lastPathComponent];
     NSString *fileExtension = [newURL pathExtension];

     // iWork files will be in the form 'Filename.pages.zip'
     if([fileExtension isEqualToString:@"zip"]) {
       if([[[newURL URLByDeletingPathExtension] pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"pages"] ||
          [[[newURL URLByDeletingPathExtension] pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"numbers"] ||
          [[[newURL URLByDeletingPathExtension] pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"key"] ) {
         // Remove .zip if it is an iWork file
         fileExtension = [[newURL URLByDeletingPathExtension] pathExtension];
         fileName = [[newURL URLByDeletingPathExtension] lastPathComponent];
       }
     }

     NSError *fileConversionError;
     fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:newURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&fileConversionError];

     // Do something with the file data here

  }
  //[url stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource]; // Necessary for security-scoped files
}
```

Relevant Apple documentation on the NSFileCoordinator options here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSFileCoordinator_class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSFileCoordinatorReadingOptions

Answer (score 0):

Did you get anywhere with this, i've tried compressing the package using something like SSZipArchive or ZipArchive but get a crash.

This is where've i've got to which might help spark some ideas.

```
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url {
 if (controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerModeImport) {
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:url includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLNameKey] options:0 error:nil];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *newDocDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *docDirectory = [dirContents objectAtIndex:0];
BOOL isDir=NO;
NSArray *subpaths;
NSString *exportPath = docDirectory;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:exportPath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir){
    subpaths = [fileManager subpathsAtPath:exportPath];
}

NSString *archivePath = [newDocDirectory stringByAppendingString:@".zip"];

ZipArchive *archiver = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
[archiver CreateZipFile2:archivePath];
for(NSString *path in subpaths)
{
    NSString *longPath = [exportPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:longPath isDirectory:&isDir] && !isDir)
    {
        NSLog(@"adding file %@", path);
        [archiver addFileToZip:longPath newname:path];
    }
}

NSData *documentData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:archivePath];

//post documentDate as zip file to server
```

}
}